# My access point router stopped connecting to the internet at the stroke of midnight and now I can't seem to bring it back

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

Today I purchased an Archer C8 to setup an access point across the building that I am currently living in. I followed the steps from this article (http://www.tested.com/tech/298-how-to-use-an-old-router-to-expand-your-wi-fi-network/) in order to ensure a proper setup. It was working perfectly when I set it up around 9 P.M. and then at the stroke of midnight all devices lost internet. I checked to see what the problem was and I found that when the new access point was unplugged the internet worked again! So I attempted to login to the router's UI only to find that it wouldn't even allow me to do that. With multiple failed attempts to login to the access point router I reset it back to factory defaults. Now I have setup the router exactly the same way as it was before but now it simply will not connect to the internet. Why is this happening? Does it have to do with me setting an incorrect static IP address or incorrectly changing the DHCP settings?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Several things you can try: 1. Check if you get internet without using the access point. 2. You will need to expand / edit your question with some details on how your stuff are set up. With the information provided as is, we can't narrow down to anything besides possible configuration issue.

Comment: What more is needed on the setup? I can provide any information necessary.

Currently I have an ASUS RT A66U on one side of the building with a CAT5E running to the C8. The computer directly connected to the C8 is using Windows and is directly wired. 

Also there is internet without the access point, sorry about not disclosing that.

Comment: One thing comes into mind (which I missed in the past) is we let both devices acting as dhcp server and they accidentally assign clashing IP address to devices. Check on your C8 if it is providing dhcp service or simply doing dhcp relay (letting Asus do the work).

Comment: I made sure that wasn't occurring as the link I provided advised. I made sure that the C8 was assigned outside of the ASUS' IP range as well.

Comment: Can you connect to the C8 over wired/wireless with static IP and get internet access? (Just want to make sure this is not just ip assignment / dhcp issue)

Comment: I can but then it resets around midnight like previously.

Answer (score -2):

This may or may not help, but have you cleared DNS cache?

`ipconfig /flushdns`

EDIT:
If you're on Windows, do that command.
If you're on Linux, restart your DHCP/DNS client.

And try to reboot.

Comment: This command would only work if the user is using Windows, and its not clear from the information provided by the author, that they are indeed using Windows.  One normally should ask that question, and wait for a response by submitting a comment, before they submitted an answer like this.

Comment: @Ramhound oh yes my bad, I'm new to answering

Comment: Some unwanted advice I am sure.  If you go around answering questions, that really are not clear, very few people will find answers to those types of questions very helpful.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: I am using Windows! Apologies for the lack of information! I will try this in a bit.